# How to persist an Avalonia Geometry object?

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm getting an error trying to serialize an [Avalonia.Media.Geometry](http://reference.avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Media/Geometry/) object with [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

```csharp
RectangleGeometry geometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(32, 32, 32, 32));
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(geometry);
```

gives
*Self referencing loop detected for property 'Standardized' with type 'SkiaSharp.SKRect'. Path 'PlatformImpl.EffectivePath.Bounds'.*

In WPF one can use `string x = XamlWriter.Save(geometry);`, but in Avalonia I can only find [AvaloniaXamlLoader](http://reference.avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Markup.Xaml/AvaloniaXamlLoader/).

Does Avalonia have a WPF [XamlWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter) equivilent? Or perhaps some other method to persist a Geometry?